# Getting the target of the current bubbling phase when using event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

I have a div that contains some buttons and I want to attach an event listener to the div that listens for events that bubble up from the buttons inside of it.

The problem I am running into is that the value of `event.currentTarget` does not appear to match what the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) say it should.

Consider the following code:

```js
$('.container').on('click', '.myButton', function(event) {
  console.log("event.currentTarget:");
  console.log(event.currentTarget);

  console.log("event.target: ");
  console.log(event.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

I am using `jquery 1.8.3`

`event.currentTarget` should be the container div, but it is being set to the button inside it instead.

How can I get around this. Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not quite. The event is delegated to `.myButton`, so the current target IS the button.

Comment: You want to get the delegate target: `event.delegateTarget`  https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/   `Description: The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was attached`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is working as it is supposed to.

In the mentioned case, event is directly attached to the button, hence currentTarget and target will always be the same.

> `$('.container').on('click', '.myButton', function(event) {});` does not mean that the event is attached to the div. It is just delegating the event. Meaning, the event will bubble up only till `.container` and the event is still attached ONLY to `.myButton`

**Case 1:** If an event is attached to the div

1. if the button is clicked then the currentTarget would be button and target would be the div.
2. if div is clicked currentTarget would be div and target would also be div

**Example**

```js
$('.container').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
  console.log(event.target);
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
  Click me
</div>
```

**Case 2: (Your case)** If event is attached to button then currentTarget and target would be button always

```js
$('.container').on('click','.myButton', function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
  console.log(event.target);
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
  Click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-currentTarget

> event.currentTarget is used to indicate the EventTarget whose
>   EventListeners are currently being processed. This is particularly
>   useful during capturing and bubbling.

So according to your code it is doing what it is supposed to. To get the parent you can try `var $target = $('event.target').parent();`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using jQuery and not native JavaScript.

```
function testClick(e){
  console.log("event.currentTarget:");
  console.log(event.currentTarget);

  console.log("event.target: ");
  console.log(event.target);
}
$('.container').on('click', '.myButton', testClick);
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].addEventListener("click", testClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption to have the container div selected is wrong with your event binding.

If you would do the following:

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){/**/});
```

Then your `event.currentTarget` would be the container.
The `event.target` can be anything below.

If you add the selector `.myButton`, events are delegated to that selector but not to the '.container'.

Comment: This removes the event from the button and makes the entire div a click event.

Comment: to make a point, yes! I'm also making that same point so no clue where you getting at.

Comment: It means that the event is supposed to be on the button, so the answer should be how to grab the container div as the target with the button having the event. This doesn't answer the question at hand. Make a point, yes, but not as an answer :)